# Splitting a string making an Array and printing over a table in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, laravel

Grabbing a string from the database and used explode function to separate the values stored.

Here is the code,

```
$data = DoctorRegistration::select('products')
     ->where('doctorid','=',$doctorid)
     ->get();

$products= explode(',', $data);

return Response($products);
```

Here is the output,

```
(2) ["[{"products":"Crocin", "Sinarest"}]"]
0
:
"[{"products":"Crocin"
1
:
"Sinarest"}]"
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

I am not sure it has converted into an array though I have used explode function and sent to ajax call.

Here is my Ajax function,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#doctorselected').on('change', function(e){
 console.log(e);
   var doctorid = e.target.value;
      var url = '{{URL::to('getdocDetails')}}';
      $.ajax({
         type : 'get',
         url  : url,
         data : {'doctorid':doctorid},
         success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
           var trHTML = '';
           $.each(data, function(i, docProducts){
             console.log(docProducts);
             for(i=0;i<=data.docProducts.length;i++){
             trHTML+=
                '<tr><td>' + '<caption> Hello </caption>'  + '</td></tr>';
              //  + data.docProducts[i].products
             }
           });
           $('#tbody').append(trHTML);
        },
         error:function(data){
           console.log('Failed');
          console.log(data);
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Here is the view/HTML

```
<div class="panel-body">
          <table class ="table table-hover">
            <caption>Sampling Tablets</caption>
            <thead>
              <th>Tablet name</th>
              <th>Quantity</th>
             </thead>
             <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
           </table>
        </div>
```

I just want to print my JSON output to a table. Please help me out with this.

Comment: @Daniel : Can you suggest anything over this?

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to convert string when you stored array or object on your database. You can use `serialize()` method.

```
$products = ["product1","product2","product2","product2"]

storable_data = serialize($products);

$this->doctorid = $id,
$this->products = $storable_data;
$this->save();

and when it comes to use..

$storable_data = DoctorRegistration::select('products')
     ->where('doctorid','=',$doctorid)
     ->get();
$products = unserialize($storable_data);

dd($products)
```

Answer (score 0):

Used to Implode to convert the array to string and Explode to Convert to the array.

And parsed used parseJSON for coversion. And printed over a table. 
Here is the AJAX code

```
success:function(data){
           console.log(data);
           var d = $.parseJSON(data);
           console.log(d);
            var output;
            $.each(d,function(i,e) {
              output += '<tr><td>'+e.products+'</td></tr>';
            });
            $('#tbody').append(output);
         },
```

Answer (score 0):

`$data` type is  `Illuminate\Support\Collection`, not `String`

as `explode()` 2nd arguments only accept string, not `array`.

to change stored value from `Collection` you can use [`map()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-map)

```
$data = $data->map(function($data) {
    $data->products = explode("," , $data->products);
    return $data;
});
return Response($data);
```